# Wait for function inside for loop

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I have code like below

```js
for (var key in array) {
  var name = array[key];
  console.log(name);

  line[val].setResultTableFormatter((builder, series, xValue, yValue) => {
    return builder.addRow(name);
  });
}
```

Here array length is 5  and `console.log(name)` is printed 5 times, but `setResultTableFormatter` is executed only once with the last array value. How to run it all 5 times?

I tried to add await like explained in other StackOverflow answers, still, It gets executed only once.

Comment: .forEach() maybe?

Comment: Foreach did the job , thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what `setResultTableFormatter` does, it looks like the function will run all those 5 times, but the function `setResultTableFormatter` just overwrites the first 4 times.

You can try and add a `console.log` inside the `setResultTableFormatter` like this:

```js
for (var key in array) {
  var name = array[key];
  console.log(name);

  line[val].setResultTableFormatter((builder, series, xValue, yValue) => {
     console.log('add row', name);
     return builder.addRow(name);
  });
}
```

Or you could run the for loop inside the `setResultTableFormatter` function (probably, again, I don't know what it does)

```js
line[val].setResultTableFormatter((builder, series, xValue, yValue) => {
  for(var key in array) {
    builder.addRow(array[key]);
  }
  return builder;
});
```

---

As a side note, using `let` or `const` would be better here. [Here's an article about why it's better](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/). Long story short in this case, the `var` will be available outside of the `for` loop, which isn't necessary. Using `let` or `const` (if you're not changing the variable afterwards) will do the job just fine and it'll stay inside the loop.